# CSS background color help needed

Tags: html, css

I want to change the background color of the of the mobile dropdown to `#000000`... but I can not work out which CSS class will do the job. I have tried to find in the Chrome inspect with no luck... please help.

http://goo.gl/WDmePH

[image]

Comment: Post the code, not a screenshot

Comment: a fiddle would make this much easier for us

Comment: He posted a site link, in case you missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do it:

```
.site--portable .site-navigation .menu-item, .site--responsive .site-navigation .menu-item {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Make sure you target mobile resolutions only, using media queries.

Comment: Thank you Bruno... that did the trick!

I have one other CSS question for the same website... with regards to the menus... the active link on the top menu is gold color, which is perfect... but on the dropdown (+features), I want the active link to be black in color as the background is gold... appreciate your help... thanks

Comment: .menu-link.level-1 {
  color: #000;
}

Comment: This is how you target submenus.

Comment: try .menu-link.level-1 {
  color: #000 !important;
}

Comment: that makes all the submenu links #000... I would just like to make the active submenu link #000 with the rest #fff ... thanks again

Comment: all fixed Bruno... I used .menu-link.level-1 { color: #fff !important; }, which fits well... thank you